# How to freeze screen while scrot -s is in effect

Tags: bash, shell, screenshot

I made a bash script so that whenever I press the PrintScreen key, scrot -s launches and saves to a specific directory with a specific name. However, when it launches, the screen still moves.

I used to use ShareX on Windows, which, when launched, will freeze the screen to let you screenshot a portion of it. Shutter also provided this, but multiple cons [such as the excruciating lag for it to launch, the persistent popup each time I took a pic] threw me off.

Is there a way to freeze the screen while scrot -s is in effect? If so, how would I be able to incorporate it into my script?

For convenience's sake, let's say this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
scrot -s [name of pic] -e [name of path]
notify-send "Screenshot saved successfully."
```

Comment: With -s parameter it will take the image of the application in which you click, is an interactive mode. Maybe what you want is -u

Comment: That's wrong. -s makes you take a scrot of a part of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

**One solution for your need may be this:**

```
sc="${HOME}/yourpic.png"; /usr/bin/scrot "$sc" -e "/usr/bin/gimp -sf $sc"
```

you can replace ${HOME} with the path you want

Once the script has run, Gimp will have been runned:

1. Select an area
2. Image :: Cut to the selection
3. File :: Overwrite 'file'.png

If you want, you can create keyboard shortcuts in Gimp for these last two tasks: **Edit - Keyboard shortcuts**.

Other utilities:

- **import** - it saves any visible window on an X server and outputs it as an image file.
- **gnome-screenshot** - screenshot application for GNOME
- **gtk-vector-screenshot** - takes screenshots of applications as PDF or
  SVG files
- **kazam** - screencast and screenshot application created with design in
  mind
- **kde-spectacle** - Screenshot capture utility, replaces KSnapshot
- **maim** - takes screenshts of your desktop
- **screenfetch** - Bash Screenshot Information Tool
- **screengrab** - Crossplatform tool for getting screenshots
- **screenie-qt** - fancy screenshot composer
- **shutter** - feature-rich screenshot program
- **xfce4-screenshooter** - screenshots utility for Xfce

Comment: Unfortunately - it doesn't work, and even if it did, it showed to have a monstrous delay. I'd rather stick to lightweight solutions so that it's instant...